# What is the role of Quantum Entanglement in the measurement of the value of a qubit?

Tags: quantum-computer

I am working on a small research for my lyceum final examination, and I have encountered a paragraph that has left me puzzled.

> In quantum physics, if you apply an outside force to two atoms, it can cause them to become entangled, and the second atom can take on the properties of the first atom. So if left alone, an atom will spin in all directions. The instant it is disturbed it chooses one spin, or one value; and at the same time, the second entangled atom will choose an opposite spin, or value. This allows scientists to know the value of the qubits without actually looking at them.

*[Source](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/quantum-computer1.htm)*

My question is, what is the difference between observing a spin and measuring the spin indirectly through quantum entanglement? In both cases, from what I have understood, the spin will be a single value (0 or 1), losing the superposition propriety that characterizes quantum computers.

Comment: I don't find the quote in the link . It's really bad worded ...  beginning with *force*. The worst part is probably *This allows scientists to know the value of the qubits without actually looking at them.*

Comment: I agree that this is badly worded, but presumably, if you've got two particles in  a state like $A\otimes B-B\otimes A$, then the difference between observing the first particle's spin directly and observing it indirectly is the difference between making an $A/B$ measurement on the first particle and making an $A/B$ measurement on the second.

Comment: @igael You can find it in the last paragraph before "Quantum Control". Quick question. What would you have used instead of _"force"_?

Comment: @WillO I am truly sorry, but there are some points that I have not understood about your comment. Please bare with me, I'm still in a lyceum (kind of a US high school).  Do the states A and B correspond to the spin of the particle? And I suppose that the particles are entangled, right? And finally, A/B stands for 50/50 chance of finding a certain spin, am I correct? Overall, to be frank, I have trouble understanding your message. Could you please rephrase it more simply? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @DavideConsonni:  $A$ and $B$ form a basis for the state space of a single particle.  By an $A/B$ measurement, I mean a measurement of an observable with $A$ and $B$ as eigenstates.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the difference between observing a spin and measuring the spin indirectly through quantum entanglement?

There isn't one.

Your question is a bit like asking "what's the difference between observing the top of a coin and measuring the top indirectly by looking at the bottom?". It's the same information accessed in a different way.

In a practical setting it may be *easier* to do one of the measurements, but ultimately they will both tell you the same thing and have the same effect on the system.

---

The thing that makes entanglement interesting is that the "same information in a different way" effect is more flexible than would be possible with the sides of a coin. There's more correlations to choose between. Read up on [Bell tests](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2464) if you really want to get to the heart of how quantum entanglement can be stronger than classical correlation.

Comment: Actually, those are not even "different ways". We measure quantum systems by entangling them with other stuff. That's sort of the only real definition of a measurement.

Comment: @DanielSank Right, measurement is just thermodynamically irreversible entanglement.